# Zip a file on remote server slow, can someone check my PS

Tags: powershell, zip, compression

Very new here, would anybody check my PS to see if I am compressing 2 files at an optimal rate?
It takes seconds when I log on through mstsc, but doing this way is really slow (in the below example, the files are so small, but I want to zip approx 600mb with 2 files):

```
$compress = @{
  
  Path = "\\servername\c$\Users\Public\Documents\1.txt", "\\servername\c$\Users\Public\Documents\2.txt"
  CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
  DestinationPath = "\\Servername\c$\temp.zip"}
Compress-Archive @compress
```

Comment: It's due to the nature of how remoting works. Try to invoke it on the remote PC to avoid serialization/deserialization.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala It has nothing to do with remoting.  Accessing UNC shares is a slow action.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley, UNC paths are a form of remoting.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala In the context of PowerShell (the tag this question lives on), Remoting as a topic almost always refers to PSRemoting (WinRM).  There is no serialization going on here, it's all network traffic.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley, powershell defaults to WinRM, but it's not the only remoting for it. I use DCOM protocols for a lot of my remoting, still a form of remoting.  The only issue i really see, is the destination still being another UNC path. Probably would be best to do it all on the remote server, then copy it over? Moving might even be faster as well. The serialization happens with the cmdlet itself, not the UNC paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) to execute `Compress-Archive` *on the remote server* (the same way you describe using RDP):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Servername {
    $compress = @{
        Path = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\1.txt','C:\Users\Public\Documents\2.txt'
        CompressionLevel = 'Fastest'
        DestinationPath = 'C:\temp.zip'
    }
    Compress-Archive @compress
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Mathias - had problems doing it like this. I get a return that Compress-Archive is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet, function etc

Comment: @ChristopherRetford What version of Windows is the remote server running? You might want to upgrade PowerShell (install Windows Management Framework 5.1)

Comment: The module may not be loaded

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just installed Windows Management Framework and presto that worked. This has cut this process by about 7 minutes. Thanksagan

Comment: kudos you just cut my CI/CD times in a tenth